# How to store mapping with inline assembly?

Tags: solidity, remix, assembly, solidity-0.8.x, solidity-0.7.x

I have a special needs, store the mapping with assembly code.
thank you very for everyone who can response this question.

for example:

```
contract assemblyMappingTest{
  mapping(address => uint) public assets;

  function save(address _user, uint _amount) public
  {
     assets[_user] = _amount;
  }

  function saveWithAssembly(address _user, uint _amount) public
  {
     assembly {
        // how to write these codes, so that it can store assets like the function "save"
     }     
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Ok, i reslove by myself.

```
contract assemblyMappingTest{
  mapping(address => uint) public assets;

  function save(address _user, uint _amount) public
  {
     assets[_user] = _amount;
  }

  function saveWithAssembly(address _user, uint _amount) public
  {
     assembly {
        mstore(0, _user)
        mstore(32, assets.slot)
        let hash := keccak256(0, 64)
        sstore(hash, _amount)
     }     
  }
}
```

Comment: How about if `assets` was a mapping of structs, how would you then write to it?